# Django NoReverseMatch at

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. На pythonanywhere начинает выдавать вот такую ошибку, после авторизации в админке, если пользователь анонимус, то сайт отображается.

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'blog.views.post_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

сама ошибка:

```
Error during template rendering

In template /home/xakslim/my-first-blog/blog/templates/blog/post_list.html, error at line 0
Reverse for 'blog.views.post_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

post_list:

```
1    {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
2   
3    {% block content %}
4                   {% for post in posts %}
5                       <div class="post">
6                           <div class="date">
7                               {{ post.published_date }}
8                           </div>
9                           <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
10                          <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Post
from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import PostForm

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte = timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts':posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})


def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: `urls.py` в urls проекта как подключается?

Comment: @FeroxTL 

    url(r'', include('blog.urls'))

Comment: Странно, что у вас локально работает. По идее вам надо либо по name получать каждый url т.е. ```redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)```, либо прикрутить namespace в include